# FPDF-Merge Error: Number of objects (22) differs with number of xrefs (23), something , pdf xref table is corrupted :(

Tags: php, pdftk

I need to fill a pdf existing form in dynamically & used fpdm in pdf form fill in PHP.

```
/***************************
  Sample using a PHP array
****************************/    
require('fpdm.php');    
$fields = array(        
    'EmpNo'  => '1234',
    'EmpName' =>'XXXX' 
);
$pdf = new FPDM('EmpDetails.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Existing Pdf form template showing error:

> FPDF-Merge Error: Object streams are not supported

Downloaded pdftk tool kit and convert file 
**Showing:**

> FPDF-Merge Error: Number of objects (22) differs with enter code here number of xrefs (23), something , pdf xref table is corrupted :(

Answer (score 2):

For rooting out this menace , we also required to install pdftk server.

1- Then type the following command in cmd as:
pdftk EmpDetails.pdf output fixed.pdf
and issue will be fixed.

We can refer https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/
for more functionalities

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28956141/Using-FPDF-to-fill-PDF.html), you need to change the 'Advanced' settings of PDFtk as following.

*Note*: This is **only available in [PDFtk Pro](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-pro/)**.

'Advanced output options:' `%PDFTK% %PDFIN% output %PDFOUT%`

In my installation, this was the default value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this problem, you need to open your PDF file with a text editor and add an empty object like this

```
23 0 obj 
<<
>>
endobj
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).